# Check class hierarchy at compile on an annotation processor

Tags: java, annotations, jvm, annotation-processing

I'm  writing an annotation processor to perform the following check at compile time:

- There's an interface `E`
- There's an annotation `@Apply` which is used to annotate methods.
- Methods annotated with `@Apply` should be called `apply` and take only one parameter of a class implementing `E`

I've gotten so far as to identify all annotated methods called `apply` and extract the name of the class they take as parameter. So I'm left with :

```
 Element method  // this is the Element that represents the `apply` method
 TypeMirror mirror //method's TypeMirror
 String paramClass // the parameter's class Name.
```

The question is: How, if at all, can I get out of these the class hierarchy representation of the parameter, so I can check it implements `E`. 
Can't use `ClassLoader.loadClass` since the class doesn't exist already, but I just need the class hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There happens to be an easy way using the `javax.lang.model.util.Types.isSubtype()` method:

```
 TypeMirror parameterTypes = mirror.getParameterTypes();
 TypeMirror typeOfE = processingEnv.getElementUtils().getTypeElement(E.class.getName()).asType();
 boolean isSubTypeOfE = processingEnv.getTypeUtils().isSubtype(parameterType, eventType)
```

With that I can check if the parameter class of the method represented by `mirror` is a subtype of the required type `E`